# Requesting Powershell script for csv, top n records of type

Tags: csv, powershell, sql-order-by

Have a csv such as this one. Would love to use powershell Import-csv

I need the last (or newest) 3 records for each type fruit.

```
#foo.csv
No, Fruit, Quality, Units, Location
1, Orange, New, 10, Village
2, Orange, Fresh, 20, City
3, Apple, New, 15, Village
4, Grapes, Fresh, 25, City
5, Apple, Fresh, 30, City2
6, Apple, Fresh, 35, City1
7, Apple, Fresh, 35, City2
8, Grapes, Fresh, 30, City2
9, Grapes, Fresh, 35, City3
```

Output would contain rows 5,6,7 for Apples and 4,8,9 for Grapes, rows 1,2 for oranges and so forth. Sort needs to be by fruit then row id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = import-csv D:\fruits.txt
$data | group Fruit | foreach {
    $_.group | select -last 3
} | sort Fruit | ft -AutoSize
```

e.g. output:

```
No Fruit  Quality Units Location
-- -----  ------- ----- --------
5  Apple  Fresh   30    City2   
6  Apple  Fresh   35    City1   
7  Apple  Fresh   35    City2   
4  Grapes Fresh   25    City    
8  Grapes Fresh   30    City2   
9  Grapes Fresh   35    City3   
1  Orange New     10    Village 
2  Orange Fresh   20    City
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!! Did not know about group and select last 3.